# error while running cap deploy:cold

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, capistrano

i get the following error after running cap deploy:cold, to deploy my rails app in amazon ec2

```
failed: "/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /mnt/Best-production/releases && tar xzf       /tmp/20130305142552.tar.gz && rm /tmp/20130305142552.tar.gz'" on db01.best.com,app01.best.com,web01.best.com
```

also, i get the following error when i just decide to proceed with creating web_tools {ALIAS=tools ROLES=web_tools cap rubber:create}

```
Rubber[ERROR]: Unable to read rubber configuration from ./config/rubber/rubber.yml
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 2 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

please help. am stuck over here

i followed railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=ec2 to the letter

question 2.

do i need an operating system instance in ec2 to successfully run rubber?

Comment: i guess the yaml has invalid syntax: Psych::SyntaxError

Comment: ok, Please elaborate it for me. I did everything according to the railscast link i have given above